# Scraper site Stream Reader violating license by linking with wrong usernames?

Tags: support, attribution, content-reuse

I'm not entirely content with bad sites reusing content anyway, but they should at least (see  `http://www.streamreader.org/gaming/questions/14249/how-to-prevent-snail-poo`, which takes content from [How to prevent snail poo?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/how-to-prevent-snail-poo)) quote the usernames correctly. Instead of mine, it states "Koonsolo," and the other user names mentioned are wrong, too; at least the profile link is more or less correct. Anyway, isn't *correct* username attribution required? (I didn't change mine for months.)

**update** added to "[the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962)"

Comment: Sorry - misread the question totally so voted to close as off topic. Please ignore.

Comment: @kiamlaluno please don't turn scraper site links into followable ones, we don't want to increase their google rank... but thanks for your edit

Comment: Also, the comments are a bit reworded each time. (*I don't remember* => *I don t do not forget*, and similar).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: that's even worse! I didn't notice this when just skimming...

Comment: Out of curiosity Tobias, was your username ever Koonsolo? You mentioned you changed it a few months ago. Is that the name you changed it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Attibution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) lists what needs to be reported for a question taken from a SE site:

1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
3. Show the author names for every question and answer
4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

The first three points don't seem to be respected, to me.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about that Kiamlaluno.
1. "Visually indicate that the content is from". At the bottom right of the page, it says "Information provided by Gaming."
2. The above text links to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/how-to-prevent-snail-poo
3. It appears to show the author names with links to their profiles.

Answer (score 2):

After researching this, it looks like a problem with StackOverflow's data dump.

Inside the Users.xml for "Stack Overflow Data Dump - Nov 2010\Content\Game Development 11-2010\112010 Game Development", the entry for user Id 88 is:

```
<row Id="88" DisplayName="Koonsolo" Reputation="216" CreationDate="2010-07-14T19:31:58.857"  EmailHash="be7e59b16461ca1aa9dd53353a81247d" LastAccessDate="2010-08-04T05:34:05.740" WebsiteUrl="http://www.koonsolo.com/rpgeditor" Location="Lier, Belgium" Age="31" AboutMe="..." Views="2" UpVotes="4" DownVotes="0" />
```

And if I understand what's going on right,

streamreader.org is showing user information:

```
Koonsolo / http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/88/Koonsolo
```

While gaming.stackexchange.com is showing:

```
Tobias Kienzler / http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/88/tobias-kienzler
```

Seems kinda sneaky for StackOverflow to release data dumps with faulty information.

Comment: I don't have access to mod tools on Gaming, but I wonder if this is simply a matter of the user changing their display name since the data dump was taken.

Comment: @Anna Lear: Said user is the OP of this question, and said they hadn't changed theirs recently. Unless it was an obsolete dump, sounds unlikely.

Comment: Try a more recent data dump -- how can you compare current data to a data dump from November 2010?

Comment: Ah, good catch. I just had the Nov dump laying around, wasn't even sure SO was still releasing new dumps.