# Board reader doesn't honour attribution guidelines

Tags: support, attribution, content-reuse

`boardreader.com` doesn't seem to honour Stack Exchange's [attribution required guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  To be specific this one:

> - Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site

1. There is no hyperlink to the question
2. There is a hyperlink to the answer, but it's cloaked as

`http://boardreader.com/jump/s7578397/f9135668/918334d61a1a2ac481f848fd4337ec3a/aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy82MTg2MzYzL2RvZXMtb24tc2VsZWN0LXRyaWdnZXItZmlyZS1kdXJpbmctYWZ0ZXItcXVlcnktcHJvY2VkdXJlLXRyaWdnZXItZmlyZXMvNjE4ODM5MSM2MTg4Mzkx`

Example question:

`http://boardreader.com/thread/Does_on_select_trigger_fire_during_after_5ft4kX3olff.html`

Comment: There is a "cloaked" hyperlink to the question -- the little "new window" image just after the title. Still doesn't meet the requirements as it isn't "hyperlink[ing] directly".

Comment: For future reference, "illegal" clones can also be added to [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the notice on these attribution required guidelines with respect to hyperlinks we provide from Board Reader to Stack Overflow.  We are changing this as we speak.  Should be up in the next 48 hours.

Comment: Thanks for implementing the changes!