# "StackOverflow Knowledge Transfer Program"?

Tags: discussion, support, legal, copyright, attribution

There has been content farms copying Stack Overflow content without proper attribution before, but this one, well...

Have a look at `http://www.404qa.com/`. The website is in Chinese, yes, but every piece of content you see is copied from Stack Overflow. The titles and content are all translated from Stack Overflow, using automatic translation tools. The site makes little reference to Stack Overflow except on the homepage, and fails almost all of the [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

A notice on the sidebar states:

> #### StackOverflow 翻译计划
>
> StackOverflow Knowledge Transfer Program 致力于将著名问答网站StackOverflow最热门的几万条常见问题翻译为中文，为广大的中国程序员提供方便。
> 在现阶段，使用翻译引擎对原有内容进行翻译，翻译质量很差。404qa将尽快对所有内容进行人工翻译。如果你愿意参加StackOverflow Knowledge Transfer Program ，请联系我们。

Roughly translated:

> #### Stack Overflow Translation project
>
> The Stack Overflow Knowledge Transfer Program is dedicated to translate the hottest question from the famous Q&A site Stack Overflow into Chinese for the convenience of all Chinese programmers. At this stage, all content is translated using automated translation tools, the quality of the translation is very poor. 404qa will as soon as possible manually translate all content. Please contact us if you are interested in joining the Stack Overflow Knowledge Transfer Program

I see no mention of this thingadongdong anywhere on MSO.

Comment: And this thing is from China? Good luck taking it down.

Comment: You could also add this site to [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/162705) [lists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824)...

Comment: The idea is good ... try to talk to them to add proper attribution, which should not be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Matt Cutts:

> But I just did a tweet at http://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/12763191490650112 to make sure we state that **auto-translation ... can be outside our guidelines and can result in pages being pruned from Google.**

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=52ce4374f956b490&hl=en

> It's great to see more webmasters localizing their websites! While Googlebot won't see translated content as duplicates, we really don't like to see automatically translated content indexed. We see it the same as other kinds of auto-generated content and would suggest using the usual methods to prevent it from being indexed (if you want to keep in on your site), for example you could add a "noindex" robots meta tag to those pages.

Comment: So, uh, what does this mean in terms of the copycat site?

Comment: it means Google will crush them if it sees them doing auto-translated content. Immediate and permanent deindexing. Makes sense, as auto-translated content is a) duplicate and b) usually of EXCEEDINGLY low quality. Not a good experience for a hapless Google searcher in any language, is it now? (manually translated content, as long as it is attributed, will probably be fine)