# What should be done about content scraping?

Tags: discussion, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

This

> http://b.vniup.com/index.php/english-learning/what-is-the-correct-conjunction-or-punctuation-for-the-following-sentence.html

looks like a content scrape of this

> [What is the correct conjunction or punctuation for the following sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53315/what-is-the-correct-conjunction-or-punctuation-for-the-following-sentence)

without any attribution to StackExchange. What's the policy, and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should [add it to the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/150562).  The list is (AFAIK) being dealt with in a reasonable amount of time for the worst offenders so you should point out any sites you see violating the attribution policy.

Though it seems the most recent inclusion has that domain added.  Perhaps you can just include your findings as details to that one.  That domain apparently is trying to "mirror" the entire Stack Exchange network, hopefully it will be dealt with ASAP.