# loopingrecursion.com: Attribution respected or not?

Tags: discussion, attribution, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

They seem to have respected all of the [criteria](https://stackexchange.com/legal) except:

> You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually
> displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content
> as coming from the Stack Exchange Network (Stack Overflow, Meta Stack
> Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User)

I'm not sure if there is a centralised question for reporting this stuff (ok, I thought there was, but couldn't find it in the limited time my patience lasted)

**EDIT** it says StackOverflow on the home page, but not elsewhere (except implicitly in links, or 'encoded' in the logo at the top)

Comment: This could be worse. They _do_ have a prominent link to SO right at the top. The source is somewhat obvious, just not quite blatantly so - this might _loosely_ fall into the 'otherwise' category.

Comment: `^-` That one. :P

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, but only on the home page, which isn't where you land if you get there via google...

Comment: @TimStone, ok, I've added it there...

Answer (score 1):

The words that follow the ones you reported are: "This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication."

What I see on that site is "Stack Overflow tag filter," where "Stack Overflow" is a link to the *Stack Overflow*'s front page. I am not sure if that qualify as clear visual indication because that link doesn't make clear the content shown in *Looping Recursion* has been taken from *Stack Overflow*.
I could clearly notice that, if I check the link reported before the questions, and see they are all links to *Stack Overflow*'s questions, or if I check the "See Answers" links and notice they take to a page on *Stack Overflow*'. Yet, the clear visual indication is asked to avoid the visitors of that site need to discover all the content of that site is taken from *Stack Overflow*.

Comment: But that's only the case on the home page. Elsewhere it is much more discreet. I landed on a tag page from Google, and only realised it was StackOverflow content when I followed a link.

Comment: I don't find that link on the front page enough as clear visual indication; the fact the link is not shown in the pages listing questions with a specific tag makes me think that it is not definitively enough. I would expect the provenience of the content is stated in any page.