# BigResource ripping off your website

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

Another website spotted that this pulling the StackOverflow content

http://asp.net.bigresource.com

For the replies, it just pushes users directly to StackOverflow.

So gets the benefits of advertising, and none of the overhead of the searches.

[Update]:

Where do we go from here - is there an official forum to raise this in?

Comment: Are you aware that SE content is licensed under Creative Commons-BY-SA?

Comment: It looks like it's aggregating from multiple sources - some of the links go to forums.asp.net. I'm having a hard time finding attribution, though.

Comment: And that's the wrong duplicate, hold on, I'll get the right one.

Comment: I don't see any attribution, though it does link to our actual posts.

Comment: @BenBrocka - I clicked around for a while and couldn't find any that linked to SO. Some examples might help us so we don't have to click any more than we have to to investigate. I feel dirty clicking around and giving them more ad impressions. :)

Comment: The first one you find with a F3 search of "jquery ajax" is an SO question

Comment: @BenBrocka - Thanks. For the record, here's the url: `http://asp.net.bigresource.com/jQuery-AJAX-calling-page-method-How-to-return-value-back-to-jQuery-gKSCPNyJ1.html`

Comment: Now I got it: [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

Comment: [They admit they're crawlers](http://www.bigresource.com/copyrights.html) but don't list attribution (it's REALLY easy guys) so I don't believe this is proper use, though they seem to think it is. They have a place where you can mail to get your site excluded though.

Comment: Per your edit, *"is there an official forum to raise this in?"* Yes, there is. You already found it. It just so happens that this has been reported before, so your question was closed as a duplicate. Please don't take offense at that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they aggregate from multiple sources (more than just SO).

Here's an example SO-scraped page:

> `http://asp.net.bigresource.com/jQuery-AJAX-calling-page-method-How-to-return-value-back-to-jQuery-gKSCPNyJ1.html`

<sup>*[(thanks, BenBrocka)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123246/bigresource-ripping-off-your-website#comment328488_123246)*</sup>

According to the other SO question [Bobby referred to in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/132734), looks like they're violating pretty much everything attribution-wise:

> *Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.*

Nope.

> *Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)*
>
> *By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.*

Not a direct hyperlink; redirects through one of their pages.

> *Show the author names for every question and answer*

Nope.

> *Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)*

Nope.

---

Looking at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/132734), `bigresource.com` is already in the list of clones violating the attribution requirements.

Comment: This is 6 months old, but I'll comment on it anyway.  BigResource is not describable as anything other than a steaming pile of horse feces.  It can try to look like SO, or other sites, and rip their questions and their answers, but it will NEVER compare. EVER.

Comment: At least in Chrome you can use the [Personal Blocklist by Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) to eliminate bigresource.com. While you're at it, eliminate w3schools.com, too! :)

Comment: More than 2 years later bigresource.com is still violating the attribution requirements!

Comment: I found a documented [procedure for reporting scrapers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/191400) by accident. Following the rules there, I sent a message to Stack Exchange via the help center. I'll post another comment or answer when SE replies to my message.

Comment: I hope I may quote from the kind reply I got: `Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're working on it.`