# What happened to the notice of posting under Creative Commons licensing?

Tags: bug, legal, copyright, creative-commons

As I post this question there is no notice that my content is being released under Creative Commons licensing.  It looks like previously there have been modfications to it [Are the SE additions to the Creative Commons attribution requirements enforceable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257962/are-the-se-additions-to-the-creative-commons-attribution-requirements-enforceabl)   But I don't find anything about it being completely removed.

I noticed it on [Pets.se](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) and it seems to be missing on all sites beta and graduated.

[image]

Where are the creative commons notices?

As pointed out by [Journeyman Geek in the answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307795/what-happened-to-the-creative-commons-licensing/307796#307796) there is difficult to see notice that user content is licensed under CC, but there is no notice to the users posting content that they are releasing content under CC.  We used to have a fairly obvious notice when posting, much like Wikipedia still does.

[image]

There is a requirement that users be notified that content is being released.

> [What happens if someone applies a Creative Commons license to my work without my knowledge or authorization?](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-happens-if-someone-applies-a-creative-commons-license-to-my-work-without-my-knowledge-or-authorization)
>
> CC alerts prospective licensors they need to have all necessary rights before applying a CC license to a work. If that is not the case and someone has marked your work with a CC license without your authorization, you should contact that person and tell them to remove the license from your work. You may also wish to contact a lawyer. Creative Commons is not a law firm and cannot represent you or give you legal advice, but there are lawyers who have identified themselves as interested in representing people in CC-related matters.

So my question remains where is the notice that tells users they are publishing under CC?

Comment: Ok, that's odd. I see it a little to the right of the stuff you have linked

Comment: Now that you point it out, I see it also to on the lower right (off of screen shot), there used to be a blatant notice when you posted that content was being released.

Comment: Well, that post talks about the footer too so....  and ugh, I don't think I remember such a notice but that's the sort of thing I'd never pay attention to.

Comment: Unless I'm very mistaken, this is part of the terms you agree to when you create your account. The only question then would be whether unregistered users get a notice. Not sure why it would be necessary every time you post if you're signed in.

Comment: hmm yeah, post a question as a AC dosen't have it https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6R7m.png . Image upload as an anonymous user has it tho https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM6AW.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

A little to the right - in fact to the bottom right of every page.

And for pets (wider screenshot so you can see the site)

[image]

I don't recall a mention in the question/answer dialogues - nor can I really find an old screenshot that easily that shows it so I'm not sure if it ever was a thing.

Posting as a anonymous user seems to have a link to the TOS

[image]

The *one* place where this is a thing is image upload - this is as an anonymous user, but the regular one's mostly the same without the top nag-banner

[image]