# Why doesn't the new TOS email or blog post mention the arbitration clause?

Tags: support, terms-of-service, arbitration-clause

Tim Post's [initial post on the new TOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here) provides a three-point summary of the new terms, along with a link to the new text and an opportunity to ask questions.

That, of course, sparked [a re-examination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309797/were-examining-the-implementation-of-arbitration-in-the-2018-tos-update), a lengthy [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer), some changes, and some [inconsistencies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310519/to-refuse-arbitration-give-us-your-name-and-address) that are still being [worked out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310463/what-happened-to-the-electronic-opt-out-of-arbitration-and-to-the-other-correc). The result of that process, which resulted in some tangible improvements, included a commitment that "more transparency is coming so that we continue to earn your trust." Great!

However, since then, we've been sent an email that includes a six-point summary of the new terms, and there's been [a blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/21/changes-to-our-privacy-and-data-policies/) with a five-point summary. Two of the three topics mentioned in the initial post are included (and expanded upon) in the email and blog post, but both communications are silent on the arbitration clause. Why?

If this change was significant enough to be one of the three things worth highlighting in the initial new TOS post, and it's certainly been the primary topic of interest to the community since then, why was it not included in the longer summaries sent to a wider audience beyond Meta.SE? How is this consistent with a commitment for more transparency?

I realize things are quite hectic with the GDPR deadline, so is the plan to send a separate email regarding the arbitration clause at a later date? I am quite happy to ascribe the motives for all this to confusion/poor communication/everything happening at once rather than malice, but some clarity as to the plan going forward would be helpful in terms of the above-mentioned commitment to transparency.

Comment: I assume it was because the email was focusing on GDPR related stuff and the arbitration clause doesn't directly have anything to do with GDPR.

Comment: @Magisch That's reasonable, but the two have been linked since the arbitration clause was added to the TOS at the same time as the other changes. The email focuses on GDPR stuff, but also serves to alert users of the new TOS (headline: "Changes to our terms and policies"). Omitting the change that has generated the most interest and discussion is notable. If there's a further communications plan once the existing issues are ironed out, that's perfectly reasonable; it would just be great if something about that plan was shared with the community in the spirit of transparency.

Comment: I would guess more is forthcoming at this point, with all the kerfuffle about the opt out not fully settled. The GDPR email had to go out by today though.

Comment: I haven't had any emails. I'm in the UK.

Comment: See also [What happened to the arbitration opt-out profile setting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311469/what-happened-to-the-arbitration-opt-out-profile-setting), also unanswered.