# What happened to the arbitration opt-out profile setting?

Tags: support, profile-page, arbitration-clause

From [a comment by Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer#comment1012464_310065) concerning the arbitration opt-out process:

> You'll get a response, and our system is pretty good at catching spoofs (if someone makes DNS lie, then, well, nobody can catch that). And **when we make the function something you access from your profile**, we'll prod you to review your setting, most likely, so the worst case is really narrow to begin with.

<sub>*(emphasis added)*</sub>

That was back in May. It's now <s>June</s> <s>October</s> <s>March</s> *September 2019*, and I don't see anything like an opt-out button on my profile page. Is it still being worked out, or was it dropped? Is email the only option?

(On a side note, the ToS notification email that came out a while ago says nothing about the arbitration clause. When did (or does) the clock start ticking on the opt-out?)

Comment: About the side note question - "Why the ToS notification email that came out a while ago says nothing about the arbitration clause", someone [already asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310564/why-doesnt-the-new-tos-email-or-blog-post-mention-the-arbitration-clause?rq=1). He got no answer.

Comment: The new ToS came into effect May 2nd. IANAL, but it seems like the 30 day opt-out period has expired.

Comment: For reference, *new users* may still have time: their 30 days starts from when they create their account.

Comment: Thanks for adding a bounty on this, as I was just coming here to do so. Back in May, we were [told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310061) "more transparency is coming so that we continue to earn your trust." I'd like to assume good faith and attribute the lack of communication to busy people rather than malice, but the promised transparency has been less than forthcoming.

Comment: I've confirmed from a fresh sock account that even new users (with a 30 days grace period for the opt-out) see no option in their profile yet. I was going to update the date but I don't want to burden the edit review queue for this.