# Is Monica's situation a good example of why you should opt out of forced arbitration?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

The [new forced arbitration clause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer) was a hot topic a while ago. I'm wondering whether [Monica's current situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it) and her plans to possibly sue Stack Exchange are a good example for why you should always opt out of forced arbitration?

Can someone shed light on what could happen if she didn't opt out, versus if she did (which I am really hoping she did)?

Feel free to move this to Law.SE if it's more appropriate there.

Comment: Can you link to something that summarises the forced arbitration controversy please, for those of us unfamiliar with it?

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310061/155659

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 I've added a link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because law question

Comment: @Unihedron - anything about Monica is “off-topic” unfortunately.

Comment: Forced arbitration doesn't protect the company from intentional malice or fraud, like, you know.... slander, libel, etc

Comment: This question is about the relationship between SE and its users, so it is very much on topic here. This is the site where we discuss how the community and SE can work together and a question about a company policy seems very much on topic.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica The "We don’t want things to come to litigation, ever" part of the post you link to is ironic in light of recent events, given that there's now significant discussion of doing exactly that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica not just discussion, I know both jhpratt and Monica currently are.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica I can't say that SE should be surprised by it, given how outrageous their behavior has been lately. And now their primary reaction has been to try to gaslight the rest of us too.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica Who is jhpratt and why are they discussing litigation against SE? I'm assuming it has to do with licensing?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica yes, see the licensing posts

Comment: @cegfault it depends on what you mean by "protect". Forced arbitration means if you want to bring a claim of libel (or anything) against SE, you are forced to use a process that is more likely to get the company a favorable result. I would say that's a form of protection.

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica I'm no lawyer, but I've dealt with issues in the past where arbitration clauses were flat out ignored by courts because of malice or fraud.  Without getting into details, I had this happen with an ISP, and day one the judge through out the arbitration clause.  Just because there's a TOS doesn't mean the court will enforce it.  Hell, judges routinely through out prenuptial agreements.  It's my understanding that if you sue SE *because of a problem with the service* it has to go to arbitration, but if you sue SE *for intentional malice* it may or may not.

Comment: Again, I don't know, I'm no lawyer, but it's worth a lawyer looking into.  I'm sure SE wants us to think arbitration is absolute, but case law tells a different story

Comment: @cegfault yes, certainly there are cases where a clause is thrown out, but I wouldn't count on it. You have to go through an additional step and have it go your way before you even get to bring a claim. It may also add an additional legal requirement. For example, in New York, libel against a private individual does not require actual malice. If malice is required to escape the forced arbitration clause, then there is a higher bar to bring your claim to court.

Comment: @cegfault in all cases you are better off opting out of forced arbitration. Even in the best case scenario, if it is thrown out, you still had to spend the money and time to go through an additional step. In these cases, the company was protected by the additional barrier to you, the individual, bringing a claim against them

Comment: Very true; I concur

Comment: @Gio I don't care about Monica. "Should you opt out of forced arbitration?" is an entirely law-based question with absolutely nothing to do with the SE Network. It's Meta Stack Exchange, not Pretend That Discussing Your Favourite News Would Be On Topic Just Because Someone Is Loosely Relevant Experts Exchange.

Comment: I did opt out, FYI.

Comment: @MonicaCellio really glad to hear that!