# Does Stack Exchange have a policy of forcing its employees into Mandatory Arbitration over Sexual Harassment claims?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-team, company

I was just reading this article released today by the Intercept

> [GOOGLE AND FACEBOOK ENDED MANDATORY ARBITRATION FOR SEXUAL HARASSMENT CLAIMS. WILL WORKERS OUTSIDE THE TECH INDUSTRY BENEFIT?](https://theintercept.com/2018/11/21/google-sexual-harassment-arbitration/)

And, I was simply wondering if Stack Exchange binds its own employees to such a mandatory arbitration clause in their employment contracts? [I know that new users are all bound to one of them too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309786/157251)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This doesn't seem all that relevant to how the SE Network is run, but in the interest of being transparent (*especially* when you have nothing to hide)...

**No. Employee claims relating to harassment or discrimination are NOT subject to any mandatory binding arbitration.**

In the terrible circumstance that an employee ever felt they had to make such a claim, they could still choose to arbitrate, since it's usually cheaper, or they could file in court at their discretion.

Comment: Cool deal, that's all I was asking. Thanks, and kudos to StackExchange for doing the right thing (for their employees).

Comment: Thanks, @EvanCarroll! For employees based in New York State, it's no longer legal to mandate arbitration for harassment, but we actually exempted these claims from our policy before that was the case - and did so globally - because we felt harassment was too critical a cultural issue to be focused on mitigation, as opposed to prevention.

Comment: Well, I'm all about giving credit where credit is due. You suck substantially less than Facebook and Google. I figured being owned by the same VC's as FB, you all got boilerplate legal work and they just changed the watermarks.