# Who serves as the General Counsel of Stack Exchange Inc.?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, legal, terms-of-service, company

I could not find any [general counsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_counsel) or other legal position in the [Stack Exchange management](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management) page.

I believe it's common for companies this size to have one, see e.g. [a company](https://www.altschool.com/about/team) from the same [a16z network](https://a16z.com/portfolio/). (I tried to get some statistics from [crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange) and [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3495447) but the corporate data over there is not complete enough, it seems.)

If there is no general counsel, who signs off legal decisions such as the [recent ToS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here)? The CEO or some delegate based on external legal advice (from whom?)? Or what else?

Comment: Why does it matter? Keep in mind the company is privately owned, they are not by any means required to publicly share how they run their operation.

Comment: It's reasonable to ask why and how decisions were made, but I'm not sure that naming a specific individual is in anyone's best interests. What can you do with someone's name that doesn't involve harassing them in some way?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm not that interested in the name, I only wonder about the structure.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Wouldn't it be more likely a *firm*, not an *individual*?

Comment: @Nemo - I suggest you write a different question, where you ask, e.g., what firm is currently representing SE and when the contract started.

Comment: General Counsel has a very specific meaning @aparente001 - it's an individual. Not that the firm name has any more relevance. I think Nemo's more interested in whether there's an internal lawyer (counsel) who deals with _everything_ or whether some recent decisions were made with external advice and then who in SE signed them off.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not that interested in the name of the firm either. Knowing whether SE employs one or several law firms and which sort of experience (copyleft? international law? privacy? etc.) would be a nice extra but just that. ⬛⬛ My question could perhaps be rephrased as "Which legal activities/competences does Stack Exchange have internally and which are outsourced, and how?" I asked about the General Counsel because it's a specific and common organisational feature, it should be easy to find out. But it was interpreted as a "personal" question. Help appreciated with editing!

Comment: @Nemo - Well, you could edit your question along the lines you just explained, and perhaps with some of ben's text, if you like it.  But I wonder if it might be better to scrap this question and start fresh with the explanation you gave me (perhaps including some ben text).

Comment: My personal guess is that the legal guidance was not provided in-house.  That's just the feeling I got from what's been said so far.  But I don't have experience with lawyers who work in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question finally received an answer [a couple weeks ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20200116043133/https://stackoverflow.com/company/management) on https://stackoverflow.com/company/management : there is now a member of the "leadership team" for "Legal", whose role is to be:

> responsible for everything legal for the company

Which sounds like a [general counsel, chief legal officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_counsel) or whatever usual name you prefer for the role: a person responsible for all the in-house lawyers and legal work, who reports to the CEO. The person currently filling the role appears to go by the title "VP Legal" on some personal profile.

Previously legal was only mentioned along with a bunch of other stuff under a title like "strategy":

> wide variety of roles including leading executive operations, revenue operations, and corporate legal

or "finance and operations":

> oversees the accounting, finance, revenue operations, corporate legal, people, and employee experience teams

Comment: [Right now](https://web.archive.org/web/20220410200709/https://stackoverflow.co/company/leadership/) (since January 2022 it seems) there's a "Chief Legal Officer", "responsible for the legal, corporate governance, and compliance functions".

Answer (score 2):

Well based off the [blog post here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/21/changes-to-our-privacy-and-data-policies/) as of 2018 it is Adam Francoeur . There is also a link for contacts to their legal team on their /legal pages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/contact)

Comment: Listed there as "Corporate Counsel" and elsewhere as "Corporate Attorney".