# What licence is subscriber content provided under 4.0, 3.0 or them all?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, creative-commons, terms-of-service

In the footer it says:

> site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). rev 2018.8.7.31273

However, in the footer under Company > Legal > '6. Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing' it instead doesn't specify which CC BY-SA licence we're releasing our content under. It also links to the CC BY-SA 4.0 license:

> The CC-BY-SA Creative Commons license terms are explained in further detail by [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), but you should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.

Since [CC BY-SA 4.0 cannot be licensed to CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses) if subscriber content is only provided under 4.0, where the footer says 3.0 it can cause users to break the licences.

The footer under Area 51 also mentions that content is licensed under CC BY-SA 2.5.

Since it's not defined which version of the license the content is provided under, I also interpret it to potentially mean all the versions.

---

What license is subscriber content licensed under?

Comment: Fixing this [was suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309773/193139) when the new ToS were introduced.

Comment: Area 51 is still listed as being licensed under 2.5...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow are moving to CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-are-moving-to-cc-by-sa-4-0)

Comment: Related update as of today: [An Update On Creative Commons Licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing)