# Can the "attribution required" link please be removed from the footer and help page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, legal, creative-commons

The footer of all SE sites links to a blog post called Attribution Required. It is also linked to in the [Help Centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

[As has been covered previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309769/256282), this so-called requirement to give attribution in a manner specified by SE is unenforceable, and violates the Creative Commons trademark usage terms.

Well good news! The new TOS earlier this year removed these requirements. And a staff member in the Teacher's Lounge told me that it was deliberate, not an oversight.

So can the link finally please be removed from the footer and Help Centre?

Comment: Imo it's more appropriate to adjust the blog to talk about proper attribution under the CC BY-SA. The main part that's not required is visually indicating it's from Stack Overflow and linking to Stack Overflow. Having a separate post to explicitly state author name and license are required when copying content, and that shortly talks about proper attribution to ambiguous usernames and suggests linking to their profile (we have [almost 10K users named alex](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/9311377) on SO)

Comment: The CC page that's linked to already explains clearly enough IMO. And the biggest problem IMO is SE thinking they can demand links not use nofollow. There's also no need to link to the author when the post is properly linked to.

Comment: I disagree with the CC page explaining that clearly. It just states author name, but you don't have the author name, you just have an SO display name. As said, that narrows it down to about 10K people for some display names, so that's not sufficient (afaik, not a lawyer). You should attribute it to one specific author. They don't have to link _at all_, certainly not in a specific way, so imo they should provide some way to track down the author (link to profile, user ID, something distinctive, username does not suffice). The CC page doesn't explain anything about that.

Comment: @Erik I don't think you understand the point: SE **cannot** add requirements to the CC licenses and still call them the CC licenses, and those licenses don't require attribution in such a form. **A pseudonym is fine.** It **does not need to be unique,** nor does a link or ID code need to be provided. Only the link to the resource itself needs to be given. A link to the author is nice but cannot be required.

Comment: The specific author can be identified through the link to the resource itself.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying at all: a link to the resource itself __is not required__ under CC BY SA 3 (the one we're using according to the footer). Only CC BY SA 4 requires a link. Proper attribution to the author is required. Since SE/SO doesn't provide distinctive user names, I suggest they might create a page talking about how to reference the author in a non-ambiguous way (such as providing an ID or link). Confusion like this is exactly why I want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been addressed meanwhile; from Wayback Machine snapshots, we can see that the footer has been updated somewhere mid 2020, around the time of the [Creative Commons Licensing UI and Data Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347758/295232). Neither the footer nor the Help Center article contain a link to that blog post anymore. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200501051551/https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) is a snapshot of that article from May 2020, with the links both in the article and in the footer, and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200601020430/https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) is an updated version from June 2020 without those links.