# The TOS and footer refer to different CC BY-SA license versions

Tags: bug, help-center, legal, creative-commons, terms-of-service

As [previously reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309773/256282), the [TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) links to version 4, but the footer and [Help Centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) to version 3. The TOS should I think say the version number in the text as well, rather than only in the link.

In addition, the preferred abbreviation is "CC BY-SA", not "CC-BY-SA".