# What's going on with revision number?

Tags: bug, status-completed, revision-number

I just saw that site revision is 1.0.0.0

> [image: rev]

Someone just dropped it to default state, or there is integer overflow?

Comment: Could it be the first version of the new design?

Comment: @TheWanderer which one is new?

Comment: the whole responsive design that's been such a big deal.

Comment: We woke up this morning and thought "ya know what? I think we finally nailed it y'all - let's call it 1.0"

Comment: @NickCraver Let's not forget about your [tweets](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1120306275701678081)

Comment: Those are just nasty rumors

Comment: @NickCraver Also, the tag wiki for [tag:svn-revision] says it's about the revision number at the bottom. If that's not correct, please rename/merge the tag.

Comment: @Nick Can you finally remove the attribution required link if you're updating that part of the code/templates?

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not touching any of that - the issue is miles away from the views.

Comment: @Sonic what makes you think it's not correct?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The tweet right after the one I linked.

Comment: Why would we remove the "attribution required" link, @curiousdannii?

Comment: @Cody because it's against the terms of the CC license, and because the staff have already said they're intending to.

Comment: @curiousdannii What? How is "attribution required" "against the terms of the CC license"? The CC BY-SA license explicitly requires attribution.

Comment: @Cody [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309769/256282). It's the contents of the blog post that are the problem. The CC BY-SA license does not let you dictate specific ways in which attribution is to be given.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is now fixed. It may be silly, but I bet others hit it so...details! TL;DR: a code move in our .NET Core migration read AssemblyVersion from an assembly that was set (via `AssemblyInfo.cs` during a build) to one that wasn't (an SDK project which doesn't have that stuff).

I figure it's best to just literally paste my commit message here:

> When we moved assembly versioning down to `StackOverflow.Common`, the footer went back to 1.0.0.0. This happened because our build replaces the versioning in `AssemblyInfo.cs` which doesn't exist anymore in .NET Core. We need to instead replace it as `<Version>...</Version>` in the `.csproj`. We may change to git versioning here later, but this maintains the date version for the moment (e.g. in the footer).
>
> This change is paired with a "File content replacer" feature on the TC builds to do the actual replacement. Again: this gets us back to working...but we should replace how all this works with built-in git versioning and a date feed from elsewhere if we want to maintain that in the footer.
>
> This fixes: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327167/whats-going-on-with-revision-number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327167/whats-going-on-with-revision-number)
>
> Note: locking the build replacement down to `StackOverflow.Common.csproj` since it replaces the `<Version>` element which catches this in `StackSnippets.csproj`:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple">
  <Version>4.5.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

> While this should be:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.5.0" />
```

> ...the tooling does that and the problem will just occur again. So let's just side-step most of the noise of such things by locking it down.
>
> Setup in TeamCity:

```yaml
Path pattern: "**/StackOverflow.Common.csproj"
File encoding: UTF-8
Search for: (?-m)(<Version>)(.*)(<\/Version>)
Match case: true
Regex: true
Replace with: $1%system.build.start.year%.%system.build.start.month%.%system.build.start.day%.%system.build.number%$3
```