# Publications that cite Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, citation

Is there a database of publications (articles, books, etc.) that cite Stack Exchange questions or answers? If not, how could I find such publications?

Comment: There's a [question here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) listing various academic papers using data from Stack Exchange. If it's not quite what you're looking for, it still might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Kendra That's very similar to my question, but I'm not looking for publications on StackExchange itself but on specific content of StackExchange. For example, a physics paper citing a Physics SE question or answer, etc.

Comment: If you're interested in physics papers you should ask on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Legally](https://stackexchange.com/legal), anyone citing a Stack Exchange post must credit the author's user profile (among other things), which looks something like this:

```
https://site.stackexchange.com/users/#####/username
```

With this information, it's possible to make [one](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2F%22) or [two](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="mathoverflow.net%2Fusers%2F") good Google Scholar queries that will get you all the results you want, with very few you don't.

Using this method I found a number of papers that cite SE posts. Here are some examples:

- [Some New Results On Even Almost Perfect Numbers Which Are Not Powers Of Two](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04248.pdf)
- [The physics and uses of graphene](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/student/amir.el-hamdy/reports/vacationessays/Graphene.pdf)
- [A finite set of local moves for Kirby calculus](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1288.pdf)
- (In Indonesian) [Pengembangan Media Pembelajaran Ebook Berbasis-Web dengan Menggunakan LaTeX pada Matakuliah Analisis Vektor](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/37337753/ebook-latex.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1499059455&Signature=QQ%2B10x1W3YHZPVtP9Tr4IU3rZzg%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DPengembangan_Media_Pembelajaran_Ebook_Be.pdf)

Comment: Relevant comment copied from a post [citing this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/103391/958): That's what the Stack Exchange TOS say, but in my view that provision is itself [illegal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209250/se-should-stop-using-the-cc-logo). Stack Exchange is not the copyright holder for that post; it is a licensee under a CC license, and does not have the right to add additional restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Using Web of Science, you can do a cited reference search. There are a few results. However, you can find much, much more using Google Scholar. Make sure after you do your search that you check the option to include citations.